# Invalid hook call calling function component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd

I have create a new project with create-react-app.

I have add the antd library (like Material UI), I have add the Router-Dom and I dont have any class component in all my project.

This is the first time I use functions component.

This is my SignIn function component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Form, Input, Button, notification, Popover, Spin, Col, Row } from 'antd';

const layout = {
    labelCol: {
       span: 8,
    },
    wrapperCol: {
       span: 16,
    },
};
const tailLayout = {
    wrapperCol: {
      offset: 8,
      span: 16,
},
};

const SingIn = () => {
    const onFinish = values => {
        console.log('Success:', values);
    };

    const onFinishFailed = errorInfo => {
        console.log('Failed:', errorInfo);
    };

return(
    <Form
        {...layout}
        name={"signup"}
        onFinish={onFinish}
        onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
        >
        <Form.Item
            label="Email"
            name="email"
            rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please input your email!' }]}
            >
            <Input/>
        </Form.Item>
    </Form>
);
}

export default SingIn;
```

This is my app function component:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import PublicRoute from "./components/routes/publicRoute/PublicRoute";
import SingIn from "./pages/singUp/singIn";

function App() {
  return (
      <Router>
          <Switch>
              <PublicRoute component={SingIn} path="/signin" exact />
          </Switch>
      </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And my index.js

```
 import React from 'react';
 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
 import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
 import App from './App';
 import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

 import './index.css';

 ReactDOM.render(
   <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
    <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
  );

 // If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
 // unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
```

This is my PublicRoute component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const PublicRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {
return (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
             <Component {...props} />
    )} />
 );
 };

 export default PublicRoute;
```

This is the error:

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See react-invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

My react version is this  "react": "^16.13.1".

And the webpack alert:

[image: webpack alert]

I spent more than 2 hours trying to solve this problem, converting all my components to functions components but I dont have more ideas.

Can someone help me?

Ok, I have take all code from SignIn component and I add directly to App component and it works.

Could be the Routes?
Maybe the way to exports SignIn?

Comment: can you share `index.js` as well? Looks like you are rendering two `Router` elements

Comment: Yes, here your and yes, but after remove the Router on the index it doesnt works, same error.

Comment: I'm thinking that maybe is the antd library, if I remove all components from that library it works. 

I going to test it with Material UI.

Comment: You don't need to use the Router component in your App.js again.

Comment: Are you using the redux?

Comment: Not right now, and if I use hooks I think that I will not use Redux.

I have remove Router from App component but still get the error.

Comment: Can you also provide your PublicRoute component

Comment: Yes, added, but also function component.

Comment: I have take all from signin component and added to App component. 

It works. 

Then, the problem could be the Route component or maybe the way to export the SignIn component.

Comment: Ok, the problem was the Switch component. 

react-router v5 includes hooks support. 

Just removing the switch works fine.